# Multiple foreach statements usage in constraints in system verilog

Tags: constraints, system-verilog

I have a requirement where to populate `bird` based on queue value `grp_q`. If the enum in `grp_q` is a bird, then set `bird.val` and `bird.ptr` with the corresponding index of `grp_q`.

I have done this through post-randomization as below.

```
module top;
  typedef enum logic [7:0] {
    PARROT,
    PEACOCK,
    DOVE,
    SPARROW,
    GOOSE,
    OSTRICH,
    BEAR,
    BUFFALO,
    CAMEL,
    DOG,
    CAT
  } group_e;

  typedef struct {
     bit [2:0] val;
     bit [2:0][3:0] ptr;
  } bird_t;

  class check;
    group_e grp_q[$] = {
      PARROT,
      BEAR,
      BUFFALO,
      CAMEL,
      DOG,
      CAT,
      PEACOCK
    };

     rand bird_t bird;

  function void post_randomize();
  int _ptr=0;
  foreach(grp_q[i])
  begin
    if (grp_q[i] == PARROT || grp_q[i] == PEACOCK)
    begin
      bird.val[_ptr] = 1;
      bird.ptr[_ptr] = i;
      _ptr++;
    end
  end

  endfunction : post_randomize
  endclass

  initial begin
     check ch = new();
     ch.bird.val = 0;
     ch.bird.ptr = 0;
     ch.bird.rand_mode(0);

     ch.randomize();
     $display("Group  = %p", ch.grp_q);
     foreach(ch.bird.val[i]) begin
       $display("Value = %d", ch.bird.val[i]);
       $display("Ptr = %d", ch.bird.ptr[i]);
     end
  end
endmodule
```

Is there any way to have a constraint for `bird` rather than using a post-randomization mechanism something like below. Basically `grp_q` is of rand type. For example I made it as non-rand.

```
foreach(grp_q[i]) {
  if (grp_q[i] == PARROT || grp_q[i] == PEACOCK|| grp_q[i] == DOVE || grp_q[i] == SPARROW) {
    << Fill bird fields>>
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have any constraints on the number of birds that appear in `grp_q`? If not, you need `bird_t.val` to be as long as `grp_q.size()`, meaning you dont need `bird_t.ptr`.

Comment: Is there any specific reason, why you don't want to use `post_randomize` function, as in your case that function makes more sense and also it is more computationally effective than randomization constraint?

Comment: Karan Shah .. Yes my requirement needs `constraints` rather than `post_randomize`